# Google Cloud Endpoints: Turn off pretty printing JSON from the server?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We are using Google Cloud Endpoints REST APIs with the Android/Java client libs. All responses are "pretty printed" JSON by default. We can add the query param "prettyPrint=false" to turn this off, but it is really annoying that we can't find a way to turn this off globally by default on the server.

Is there a way to turn off pretty printing with cloud endpoints server-side?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can [file a feature request](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java). For Python, it would be [here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-python).

Comment: Thanks for some verification that it's impossible. I'll file the request.